# NormalizationHelper - how to save it to a file

Tags: encog

I was looking at the example below, but couldn't find a way to save the NormalizationHelper to a file as suggested in the comment.
I tried both method below, the first one throw an error, and the second one saves it, but then throw an error loading the file with  EncogUtility.LoadEGB2Memory

Thanks for your time
Regards
Vincenzo

EncogDirectoryPersistence.SaveObject
EncogUtility.SaveEGB

encog-dotnet-core-3.3.0\ConsoleExamples\Examples\Guide\Timeseries\SunSpotTimeseries.cs

```
        // Loop over the entire, original, dataset and feed it through the
        // model. This also shows how you would process new data, that was
        // not part of your training set. You do not need to retrain, simply
        // use the NormalizationHelper class. After you train, you can save
        // the NormalizationHelper to later normalize and denormalize your
        // data.
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same serialization issue in Encog 3.3 last year, and fixed it in a branch of the github repository. See the Encog bug report ["NormalizationHelper is not serializable #194"](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/issues/194).

It doesn't look like a newer version has been released since. The issue is marked for inclusion in v3.4.

One workaround in the meantime would be to download the current development codebase from the github repository.